# How to serialize tuples in django rest framework? Or, is there any way to convert tuple into queryset?

Tags: django-rest-framework

My `views.py` contains a view like:

```
class RankViewSet(generics.mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                generics.mixins.ListModelMixin,
                viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    def get_queryset(self):
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            query = "SELECT ... "
            cursor.execute(query)
            row = cursor.fetchall()
        return row
```

Here, `get_queryset(self)` returns some tuples like following:

```
((name1, college1, semester1), (name2, college2, semester2), (name3, college3, semester3), ...)
```

All of the fields are from different models, so I have to fetch these data using raw sql. How can I serialize this tuple in django rest framework? Or Is there any way to convert tuple in queryset?

Comment: Given that you're accessing the database through a direct connection and not through Django's ORM, is there any reason why you need to be using `get_queryset()`?

Comment: I had to customize queryset. So, I need to override `get_queryset()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only just seen this question but answer may still be useful...

Off the top of my head you have a few options:

1. serializers.ListField -as you basically have a list of lists, if the content is all the same type you can do child=serializers.ListField(child=serializers.CharField())
2. serializers.SerializerMethodField()..and call mySerialiser(many=True) with the set

   `name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    def get_name(self, obj):
        return obj[0]`

Having said this unless you have a very specific reason to use a raw sql query, as you are using django you should take advantage of its ORM engine and then you can use rest_framework model serializer. If speed is an issue you can use .only() and .defer() with your queries.